# NASM - different behaviour depending on register

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have a string taken from user, saved into "variable" named *num*. Now, I load the first character to this string into register for further processing. It looked like

```
mov rax, [num]
cmp rax, '5'
je character_equal_five
```

I got some problems in later part so I started debugging this one line and for input like "522314" I figured out that rax register's value was something about 2000, while it should be five's ascii code. Doing

```
xor rax, rax
mov rax, [num]
```

did not help either. So I finaly done this

```
mov al, [num]
```

and was finally successful to get reliable results. My question is: why does it happen? Why can't I use a bigger register for this task?

Comment: Because when you do `mov rax, [num]` you're loading eight bytes, not one. Use `movzx` if you want to load one byte zero-extended into a larger register.

Comment: When you use `rax` as an operand to `mov`, you are telling the assembler that you want to move enough bytes to fill `rax`. When you use `al` (which represents only the lower 8-bits of the register) you are telling the assembler to move one byte, just what fits in `al`.